# how to do an expression inside the .scala.html file in play framework

Tags: html, scala, playframework-2.0

I want to ask how to do an expression inside the .scala.html file in play framework. You can do the scala codes by puting an @ sign for every scala code. You can also define a variable by:

```
 @defining(0){ i => 
 @ i
 }
```

the code above displays 0 but what i want to ask is how can i do an expression on the variable i. for example i want to do:

```
@i = i + 1
```

whenever i type this inside the .scala.html file in displays:

```
0 = i + 1
```

what i want is i modified after an expression.

THANK YOU.

Comment: What happens if you remove spaces ? I think the @ magic char is just a way to tell the interpreter that what follows is scala language until the next separator ( \n \t ...). 
You can also put brackets to extend the power of @.

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression:

```
@i = @{1 + 1}
```